# aiogram Кнопка назад

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

**Мне надо сделать кнопку назад, пытался сделать через состояния но у меня не получается, помогите кто знает**
Разные способы перепробовал, и много информации искал о FSM, в общем не чего не помогает. Пишу на *aiogram*

```
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters import Command, Text
from aiogram.types import Message

from handlers.users.keyboard import start_menu, Katalog
from loader import dp
from states.test import Test


@dp.message_handler(Command('Start'))
async def start(message: Message):
    await message.answer('ЭтоТест', reply_markup=start_menu)

@dp.message_handler(Text(equals='Каталог'))
async def igry(message: Message):
    await message.answer('Вот наш каталог Тест', reply_markup=Katalog)

@dp.message_handler(state=start_menu)
async def answer_first_name(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    text = message.text
    if text == "Назад":
        await message.answer('Ты вернулся назад', reply_markup=start_menu)

state.py

from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import StatesGroup, State


class Test(StatesGroup):
    Q1 = State()
    Q2 = State()

keyboards.py

from aiogram.types import ReplyKeyboardMarkup, KeyboardButton

start_menu = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(
    keyboard=[
        [
            KeyboardButton(text='Каталог')
        ]
    ], resize_keyboard=True
)

Katalog = ReplyKeyboardMarkup (resize_keyboard=True,row_width=2)
But = ['Игры', 'Фильмы', 'Назад']
Katalog.add(*But)
```

Comment: Что это такое ??

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой и, наверное, верный вариант - CallbackQuery. Для Вашего примера это будет выглядеть примерно так:

```py
start_text = "ЭтоТест"
start_keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup().add(InlineKeyboardButton(text="Каталог", callback_data="Catalog"))


@dp.message_handler(Command('Start'))
async def start(message: Message):
    await message.answer(start_text, reply_markup=start_keyboard)

@dp.callback_query_handler(text="Start")
async def start_callback(query: CallbackQuery):
    await query.message.edit_text(text=start_text, reply_markup=start_keyboard)

@dp.callback_query_handler(text="Catalog")
async def catalog(query: CallbackQuery):
    keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1).add(
        InlineKeyboardButton(text="Игры", callback_data="Games"),
        InlineKeyboardButton(text="Фильмы", callback_data="Films"),
        InlineKeyboardButton(text="Назад", callback_data="Start")
    )

    await query.message.edit_text('Вот наш каталог Тест', reply_markup=keyboard)
```

Comment: Круто, но это для инлайн кнопок, а мне нужно для обычных сделать, но за это тоже спасибо, я не знал как на инлайн кнопках делать кнпоку назад